# react native IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to set local data for view with unknown tag

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a react native application, after I upgrade react native from 0.47.2 to 0.50.3, I got a random crash uncaught exception only happens on Android:  IllegalViewOperationException:Trying to set local data for view with unknown tag.

below is the crash log

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to set local data for view with unknown tag: 36
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.setViewLocalData(UIImplementation.java:246)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule$3.runGuarded(UIManagerModule.java:357)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.GuardedRunnable.run(GuardedRunnable.java:21)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I want to ask if anyone knows the root cause of the crash, and how to fix it.

I am also googled how to capture the exception and find the post http://coofee.github.io/post/catch-react-native-IllegalViewOperationException/
but do not know how to do it exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: The issue should be fixed on react native 0.51.0-rc.1.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f2c6877b91963878f36ec42f5f865427bc69488c#diff-e40bcf61507821200dcf1f573eb717e3